# My PHP script for comparing dates is not working properly

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 dates in the database. One is in the past, and other is in the future. I want to check if the current time is between those two dates. Everything works locally, but not on the server.

The server is in a different timezone, but if I echo the results (in comments), everything shows as it should. Dates in the database are saved in the correct timezone, so I do not apply setTimezone to those.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Belgrade');
$start_date = new DateTime($popup_start);
$end_date = new DateTime($popup_end);
$current_date = new DateTime();
$current_date->setTimezone($timezone);
//echo $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'<br>';
//echo $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'<br>';
//echo $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'<br>';
if($start_date < $current_date AND $end_date > $current_date) {
  echo 'true';
}
else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

The code above always goes to false for some reason.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual values of  `$popup_start`,`$popup_end`,`$current_date` ?

Comment: If I uncomment three lines, this is what I get:
2019-08-03 17:11:00   
2019-08-03 17:24:00  
2019-08-03 17:22:03

Comment: Please, `$popup_start`,`$popup_end`

Comment: Sorry. Those two variables are loaded from the database, and this is what they look like in db: 2019-08-03 17:11:00 and 2019-08-03 17:15:00. They are stored as datetime, and they are only beeing loaded with MySql, no additional changes are made on them.

Comment: What is your current timezone on the server running PHP code? Can you print the out the value of those datetime object before this line: `$current_date->setTimezone($timezone);` please?

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I solve this by adding date_default_timezone_set();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime()` is compared in UTC time reference (not based on format('Y-m-d H:i:s')).
The universal time reference (probably Unix Epoch seconds) is set on the DataTime instancing and does not change by `->setTimeZone()`, that just affects the output, but it's still the same UTC time.
You have no TZ reference in the DB, so $start_date gets your local TZ when parsed. Let's say TZ_REMOTE is the timezone of the datestimes in the DB, and TZ_LOCAL is the local TZ. Then what happens is (pseudocode):

```
$start_date <- (($popup_start TZ_LOCAL)=>UTC)
$current_date <- (now()=>UTC)
```

So you have not gotten rid of the TZ difference in any way, it's still TZ_LOCAL dates.
What you can do is compare the textual representations, not the DateTimes:

```
if($popup_start < $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:I:s') && $popup_end > $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:I:s'))
```

Because, like I said, `->setTimeZone()` will not alter the actual time, but it will alter the output of `->format()` to convert the UTC datetime to the specified TZ.

Comment: Thank you for your time and clarification. I didn't know that ->setTimeZone() doesn't affect the value. However, I have made a bit different approach, I simply used date_default_timezone_set();

Comment: You're welcome. To further avoid such problems in general, the usual practice is to store DB datetimes in UTC, and convert them app-side to the TZ you need. This way, datetimes in the DB will always be consistent (comparable with one another) in the same known space that is independent of the server setup. Or you can save the TZ info along with the datetime in a separate text field.